# bash: updating an XML document when item to be modified is below grepped element

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have following XML (captured in a variable from curl output) that I need to modify in bash

```
<hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
    <name>SPRINT</name>
    <description></description>
    <defaultValue>10</defaultValue>
</hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
```

I need to look for name tag with value SPRINT and increment the subsequent defaultValue so that XML becomes:

```
<hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
    <name>SPRINT</name>
    <description></description>
    <defaultValue>11</defaultValue>
</hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
```

Quick question, how do I do that?

### Details on what I've done

I am kind-of able to achieve this (thanks to SO) using following commands:

```
config=$(curl "$JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/config.xml")
LAST_SPRINT=$(echo "$config" |  sed -n '/<name>SPRINT<\/name>/{n;n;p}' | sed -n -e 's/.*<defaultValue>\(.*\)<\/defaultValue>.*/\1/p')
NEW_SPRINT=$((LAST_SPRINT+1))
updated_config=$(echo "$config" | sed -e "s/<defaultValue>$LAST_SPRINT<\/defaultValue>/<defaultValue>$NEW_SPRINT<\/defaultValue>/")
```

This is not efficient, and potentially incorrect, because:

- I am echoing the XML ($config) twice and performing operations on it
- There potentially might be some other defaultValue tag with same value as LAST_SPRINT that I could be modifying, instead of the defaultValue following name tag with value SPRINT

As a side note, the name tag containing value SPRINT is guaranteed to occur only once in entire XML. And yes I know bash/sed may not be the best way to do this, but I am limited to packages/tools present by default on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.

Comment: Structured data should be manipulated using structured tools.  Using `sed` to manipulate XML is just too error-prone in the general case.  People will be reluctant to post even obvious answers because they tend to end up with a never-ending flood of "it doesn't work in this particular corner case" follow-ups.

Comment: Is the snippet you are showing actually the complete XML document?  Where is the "grepped" part actually, or is there no `grep` involved, or is the actual XML document really bigger than what you are showing?

Comment: "Can't use an XML editor"? Really? Even if you don't have xmlstarlet, you certainly have Python, and it ships with XML parsers you can use from bash without too much trouble. And you also almost certainly have `xsltproc` -- which is standard on just about every Linux install since it's commonly used to format documentation, and can also do the job. Instead of saying "can't use any tool within genre X", if you instead said "can only use tools included with a base install of Ubuntu X.Y" or "can only use tools included with Fedora 12" or somesuch, that would be *much* more helpful.

Comment: @tripleee, ...since the document format is that of a Jenkins config, the actual document is quite certainly larger.

Comment: @triplee, The actual XML is much larger. When I say grep, I mean the line "<name>SPRINT</name>". Sorry, couldn't think of a better way to put it. Please feel free to update

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks. Pardon my naïvety on shell programming. Updated question to reflect OS - and yes I could use anything that is directly available.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, lsb_release is not available, I do have a SuSE-release:
cat ./SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I've edited the question to reflect SLES 11, and will look up which versions of Python, xsltproc, etc. it ships when opportunity permits.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I tried to do a python, but got stuck, because this script is part of a larger script where I am iterating over an array of jobs doing a curl to get their current configs, and updating them - simple tasks in a shell script (which I understand), but looks pretty complicated in python (which I dont know). So, I am gravitating towards use of commands directly available from OS

Comment: @Ram, I wasn't proposing that you do the whole thing in Python, just that you use that specific little snippet of python from your larger shell script.

Comment: @Ram, ...I've updated my answer with a demonstration of how to do that.

Comment: (...btw, as an aside, all-caps shell variables are bad form; see fourth paragraph of the relevant POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, defining the namespace of variables with at least one lower-case character as that reserved for application use; all-caps environment variables is the namespace used by variables with meaning to the shell or system, so using that same namespace risks overwriting important environment variables by mistake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right tool for this job is not `grep`, but an XML-aware tool such as XMLStarlet.

To do the increment-by-one you requested natively, that would look like:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition[./name="SPRINT"]/defaultValue' \
  -x '. + 1' <in.xml >out.xml
```

To assert a value known to your outer shell script, by contrast, would instead be:

```
newValue=20

xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition[./name="SPRINT"]/defaultValue' \
  -v "$newValue" <in.xml >out.xml
```

---

The above were tested against the following document, which just wraps a root element around what you already had:

```
<root>
  <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
    <name>SPRINT</name>
    <description/>
    <defaultValue>10</defaultValue>
  </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
</root>
```

If it doesn't work against your actual document, the most likely cause is that these elements are not in the default namespace due to a `xmlns=` declaration at a higher level in the document; when asking questions that involve XML documents, such declarations need to be included to allow for fully responsive answers.

---

Also, a Python answer using only modules built into the 2.7-series interpreter (since you specified that you can't install 3rd-party tools):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(sys.stdin.read())
for node in doc.findall('.//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition'):
    name_el = node.find('./name')
    if name_el is not None and name_el.text == 'SPRINT':
        default_el = node.find('./defaultValue')
        if default_el is None: continue
        default_el.text = str(int(default_el.text) + 1)
print ET.tostring(doc)
```

...pipe your content through that script, and the `defaultValue` for the `SPRINT` parameter will be incremented.

To wrap this in a shell function would look something like the following:

```
# assign python code to a shell variable
_increment_sprint_script=$(cat <<'EOF'
import sys, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(sys.stdin.read())
for node in doc.findall('.//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition'):
    name_el = node.find('./name')
    if name_el is not None and name_el.text == 'SPRINT':
        default_el = node.find('./defaultValue')
        if default_el is None: continue
        default_el.text = str(int(default_el.text) + 1)
print ET.tostring(doc)
EOF
)

# define a function that calls the interpreter with that code
increment_sprint() { python -c "$_increment_sprint_script" "$@"; }

# ...then you can just pipe through it.
updated_config=$(curl "$JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/config.xml" | increment_sprint)
```

Comment: that does it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Lord help me this is the ugliest `awk` one liner I've ever built, but it will do the job if no one else offers up anything prettier in `sed`; or `awk`, for that matter.

I believe you could get something much cleaner with some regex, but I was worried it might be more error prone with oddball edge cases and the like.

Furthermore, sed and awk and grep are just not great tools for this, as you mentioned. Literally any other tool that can handle XML gracefully would be preferred over this.

Anyway, here's my abomination:

```
awk -F"[<>]" 'foundSprint==1 && $2=="defaultValue" {$3=$3+1; print $1"<"$2">"$3"<"$4">";alreadyPrinted=1;foundSprint=0;} $2=="name" && $3=="SPRINT" {foundSprint=1} alreadyPrinted!=1{print $0; alreadyPrinted=0}' infile > outfile
```

There's three blocks to this script.

1. If we have `foundSprint` and the tag is `defaultValue` then increment the value, which will be in field 3 `$3` when we split the line by "<" or ">". Then increment the value, and print the line out replacing the appropriate "<", ">" that were stripped because they are treated as delims by awk. Lastly, set the `alreadyPrinted` variable to 1 so we don't reprint this line in step 3.
2. Here we look for `Sprint` in tag `name`. If we find it then we set that `foundSprint` variable to 1 that we used in step 1.
3. Finally, if we didn't already print the line in step 1, then print it now and reset that `alreadyPrinted` variable to something other than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have "BASH" in the title, have a look at this (pure) bash implementation :)  No other binaries needed, and it does what you want.

inputfile contains your given example text

Enjoy, 
--bvk

```
#!/bin/bash
FILEN=inputfile.txt

incrementit() {
        local IFS="\n"
        REPLACING=0
        while read line; do
                if [[ "$line" == *"<name>SPRINT</name>"* ]] && [[ $REPLACING == 0 ]]; then
                        REPLACING=1
                fi
                if [[ "$line" == *"<defaultValue>"*"</defaultValue>"* ]] && [[ $REPLACING == 1 ]]; then
                        CURVER="${line//<defaultValue>/}"
                        CURVER="${CURVER//<\/defaultValue>/}"
                        echo -e "    <defaultValue>"$(( CURVER + 1 ))"</defaultValue>"
                        REPLACING=0
                else
                        echo "$line"
                fi
        done
}

incrementit <$FILEN
```

Comment: Consider `printf` over `echo -e` -- any shell which implements `echo -e` to do anything but print `-e` on its output is directly contravening the POSIX sh standard, and with the `xpg_echo` option set, bash doesn't do this either. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: Also consider lower-case names for your own variables -- this is described as a namespace reserved for application use, to prevent user scripts from unintentionally overriding variables with meaning to the shell and system. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: (I'd also suggest declaring `REPLACING` and `CURVER` as locals, so you aren't leaking them into global namespace outside your function).

Comment: Good points Charles, thanks. That would make it more neat.  I'll leave those as an exercise for the reader though; gotta run, the weekend just started!

Comment: ...oh, and one last thing -- making it `while IFS= read -r line` instead of `while read line` would prevent any literal backslashes from being removed from the document by this pipeline, and prevent trailing whitespace from being stripped. But still, these are all incremental improvements; if someone is willing to accept the inherent fragility of using non-XML-aware tools to modify XML content, so be it.

Comment: Oh @CharlesDuffy (while putting on my jacket) I  agree that using XML tools to modify XML is the better solution here =] 

But hey, the title said Bash. Would I do it in bash (or perl, or sed, or ed, or ... ) in production? Hell no! XD

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed specifically to transform XML files to customized structures. Bash can run such transformations with [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html):

**XML** *(assumed structure)*

```
<root>
    <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <name>SPRINT</name>
        <description></description>
        <defaultValue>10</defaultValue>
    </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
</root>
```

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition[name='SPRINT']"/>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition[name='SPRINT']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="name|description"/>
      <defaultValue><xsl:value-of select="number(defaultValue) + 1"/></defaultValue>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Bash** line

```
shell> xsltproc transform.xsl input.xml > output.xml
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
    <name>SPRINT</name>
    <description/>
    <defaultValue>11</defaultValue>
  </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
</root>
```